# Is there plugin for WP to show latest news with specific word in title or somewhere?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, keyword

I need help with WordPress. For example, I have 100 posts in my blog, and only one post has a word: "HOT". I'd like to show this post on the right side (like widget). Can you advise me something?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it is either too broad or asks to recommend an off-site resoure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins like "Recent Posts Widget Extended" that can filtered by tag or filter the post query on functions.php like :

```
add_filter( 'rpwe_default_query_arguments', 'your_custom_function' );
function your_custom_function( $args ) {
    $args['s'] = 'HOT'; 
    return $args;
}
```